# cond style statements in erlang

Tags: erlang, lisp, case

Coming from a Lisp background, Erlang's `case` statement seems a bit baffling to me. I'm currently working on the Sieve of Eratosthenes problem, trying to generate a list of the prime factors of a number N. However I can't seem to migrate what seems like a simple `cond` statement in Lisp  to the equivalent in Erlang.

So far I have constructed an `if` statement that resembles how I would go about things in Lisp:

```
prime_factors(N) -> pf_helper(N, [], 2).


pf_helper(M, PL, D) ->

if 

  prime_p(M) == true -> [ M | PL ];

  (prime_p(D) == true) and (M rem D == 0) -> pl_helper(M div D, [ D | PL ], D+1);

  (prime_p(D) == true) and (M rem D /= 0) -> pl_helper(M, PL, D+1);

  prime_p(D) == false -> pl_helper(M, PL, D+1)

end.
```

I am aware that this will not compile since I can only have `BIF` calls in my guards. The problem is that I cannot conceptualize how this would run as a `case` statement, since `case` handles a conditional expression on one argument. In the case that I represent the three `pf_helper` arguments in a tuple:

```
pf_helper(M,PL,D) -> pf_helper({M, PL, D}).
```

what would the patterns be inside the case statements that correspond to the conditional expressions

```
   prime_p(M) == true 

  (prime_p(D) == true) and (M rem D == 0) 

  (prime_p(D) == true) and (M rem D /= 0)

  prime_p(D) == false
```

?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use some guards:

```
case {prime_p(M), prime_p(D)} of
  {true, _} -> [M|PL];
  {false, true} when (M rem D == 0) -> ...;
  {false, true} when (M rem D /= 0) -> ...;
  {false, false} -> ...
end
```

I think Anthony Ramine was working on implementing `cond` at one point.